# check Recursively if i can create a sum of given number from a list of numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get a number and a list. I must find the maximum number of numbers in the list to give me the sum of the given number.

```
def calc_max_baggage (weights, W):
    if W==0: # if W == 0 or weights == []: is the same.
        return 0
    elif weights==[]:
        return 0
    elif sum(weights)==W:
        return len(weights)
    elif weights[-1]==W:
        return 1
    elif W==0:
        return 1
    option1 = 0+calc_max_baggage(weights[:-1], W)
    option2 = 0+calc_max_baggage(weights[1:], W)
    return max(option2,option1)
print calc_max_baggage([3,1,2,3,2,1],6)
```

Expected output: 4 -- the largest is 1 + 2 + 2 + 1

Actual output: 3

Comment: Check your indentation

Comment: Added a couple edits to fix your indentation. I also added a comment to specify how you could use `or` to cope with your first two if statements. Your expected output is 4, but what is the actually outoutput from running your code?

Comment: the ouyput is 3.

Comment: >>> calc_max_baggage ([5],0)
 
 
0
 
 
>>> calc_max_baggage ([],5)
 
 
0
 
 
>>> calc_max_baggage ([5],4)
 
 
0
 
 
>>> calc_max_baggage ([5],5)
 
 
1
 
 
>>> calc_max_baggage ([1,1,1],2)
 
 
2
 
 
>>> calc_max_baggage ([1,1,1],7)
 
 
3
 
 
>>> calc_max_baggage ([4,2,1,3],5)
 
 
2
those are the expected output.
([3,1,2,3,2,1],6):
[2+2+1+1]->4 
[3+1+2]->3
[3+3]->2

Comment: Can you tell me where you will get 4 from when 4 doesn't exist and you don't actually calculate (change) the numbers at all?

Comment: I need to find all sums of numbers from the list that give me the guven number W.

Comment: and return the max sum number that give me the sum for example:
([3,1,2,3,2,1],6): [2+2+1+1]->4 [3+1+2]->3 [3+3]->2 return 4

Comment: I fail to see how this algorithm is intended to find the maximal solution.  There is redundant or unreachable code, which suggests a logic error -- and you haven't explained your intended logic.  The target sum problem is covered quite well on Stack Overflow and elsewhere; I suggest that you pick one of those algorithms.

Comment: I can't find a solution.
I don't know why but this code with sorted is working

Comment: Please edit your answer with the answers to my questions, it's horrible to try read this otherwise:)

Comment: I can not understand you @Swift

Comment: @Swift: I edited the expected output into the question.

Comment: @Swift: your other question misses the point: `4` comes from the maximal set size that sums to `6`.  There are many ways to sum to `6` from the given list, but the largest is `1 2 2 1`, length of 4.

Comment: @John: you've asked twice if we "have any ideas" for doing this without loops.  Again, *do your research*.  The target sum problem is solved in many places, often without loops and using recursion.  Before you ask *us* whether we have any ideas, you're supposed to check those for yourself.  If you have trouble with your implementation *after* that, post another question.  I think we've bottomed out on this one.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Your expected output is incorrect. This is recursively finding the sum of numbers that equal W and then returning the total count of numbers used to find the sum of W. E.g. `1+2+3=6` therefore return 3

Comment: I am looking for the max so it should be 1+1+2+2

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by recursively trying different combinations of elements from the list (Dynamic Programming). like this.

```
def calc_max_baggage(li, tot, current_bagage=0, max_baggage=0):
    if tot == 0 or len(li)==0: return current_bagage
    if tot < 0: return 0
    for i in range(len(li)):
        temp = calc_max_baggage(li[:i] + li[i+1:], tot-li[i], current_bagage+1)
        if temp > max_baggage:
            max_baggage = temp
    return max_baggage
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question. Please ask someone else to explain why it works because I only understood this to make it work for your answer:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations


weights = (3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1)
W = 6
# weights = (3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1) / w = 6 / Output: 4
# weights = [1, 1, 1] / w = 2 / Output: 2
# weights = (1, 1, 1) / w = 7 / Output: 3
# weights = [4,2,1,3] / w = 5 / Output: 2
# weights = [5] / w =5 / Output: 1

def powerset(iterable):
    """
    :param iterable: the iterable you want to find all combinations for
    :return: each combination of the iterables in this example:
    :example: 
    weights = (3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1)
    w = len(weights)
    powersets = []
    for x in powerset(weights):
        if sum(x) == w:
            print(x)
            powersets.append(len(x))
    Output >>>
    (3, 3)
    (3, 1, 2)
    (3, 1, 2)
    (3, 2, 1)
    (3, 2, 1)
    (1, 2, 3)
    (1, 3, 2)
    (2, 3, 1)
    (3, 2, 1)
    (1, 2, 2, 1)
    4
    """
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def calc_max_baggage(weights, W):    
    powersets = []

    # for x in powerset(weights):
    #     if sum(x) <= w:
    #         print(x)
    #         powersets.append(len(x))
    # Because you said no for loops somewhere:
    powersets = [len(x) for x in powerset(weights) if sum(x) <= W]
    print(max(powersets))
calc_max_baggage(weights, W)
```

Which was lifted from:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Hope this helps :)

Disclaimer: valid python3 code. Unsure if changing print to remove parentheses will work but you can try :)

Comment: Thx!! But I have to do it without a loops

Comment: There aren't any loops though? That isn't a loop, it's called list comprehension. Why are you unable to use a loop exactly? That seems very backwards